# Is there a clean way of referencing generic classes in a non-generic context?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Consider the following:

```
public interface ICleanCoder
{
    void DoSomeCoding(object task);
}

public interface ICleanCoder<T>
{
    void DoSomeCoding(T task);
}

...

public class TestCleanCoding
{
    void RegisterCleanCoder(ICleanCoder coder);
}
```

I have to have the initial non generic interface to enable a non generic reference to it later on. I know that technically that makes perfect sense, but the solution smells a little rotten to me, and I was wondering if I was missing something.

Comment: You seem to have a solution, but haven't posted it. Maybe we could suggest someting if you did.

Comment: @Noldorin - ?? not sure what you mean! That is the solution up there; the non generic implementation of the interface *as-well* as the generic one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, that's the only way to do this, unless you want to make TestCleanCoding a template too (which is a reasonable design decision and won't throw away the benefits of ICleanCoder being a template); also, you're leaving out an important part:

```
public interface ICleanCoder<T> : ICleanCoder
{
    void DoSomeCoding(T task);
}
```

Otherwise, your templated interface is unrelated to your base interface.